# Rewriterule in .htaccess priority conflict

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Here are the rewriterules for .htaccess. But I am facing a problem.
Here is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dashboard/sample_proj/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule t([\d]+)/ threads/$1/  [R=301]
RewriteRule f([\d]+)/ forums/$1/  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule t([\d]+)-([\d]+)/ threads/$1/page-$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule t([\d]+)/#post([\d]+) threads/$1/#post-$2 [R=301,L]
```

But this is a problem because there is a priority conflict between the urls.
For Example 
    https://www.url.com/t3550/#post44859
redirects to https://www.url.com/threads/3550/#post44859 but should instead should redirect to https://www.url.com/threads/3550/#post-44859 (this is because there is a conflict between the first and the fourth rule).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fragments, the things after `#`, **are not sent to the server.** They're purely local in the browser, and only evaluated by the browser. A rule matching on `#` can never match, because the server will never get to see a URL fragment.

Comment: Can u provide a temporary solution ?

Comment: No, because what you're trying to do is fundamentally impossible. I have no idea what other constraints you have for what you're trying to achieve, so I can't even advice any other approach.